# Find and replace VBA macro too large

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, large-data

I'm using this macro, to search and replace values in multiple word documents.

The problem is, that I have to many values, that should be changed and it won't run, saying :

> Procedure is too large

I tried to find a solution, but nothing worked so far. I would be really grateful, if someone could offer a solution!

```
Sub DoReplace()

Const Find1 = "FIND TEXT"
Const Replace1 = "REPLACE TEXT"

Const Find2 = "FIND TEXT"
Const Replace2 = "REPLACE TEXT"

Const Find3 = "FIND TEXT"
Const Replace3 = "REPLACE TEXT"

Dim FilePick As FileDialog
Dim FileSelected As FileDialogSelectedItems
Dim WordFile As Variant  ' FileName placeholder in selected files loop
Dim FileJob As String    ' Filename for processing

Dim WorkDoc As Object
Dim WholeDoc As Range
Dim FooterDoc As Range

On Error GoTo DoReplace_Error

    Set FilePick = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FilePick
        .Title = "Choose Report Template"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Word Documents & Templates", "*.do*"
        .Filters.Add "Word 2003 Document", "*.doc"
        .Filters.Add "Word 2003 Template", "*.dot"
        .Filters.Add "Word 2007 Document", "*.docx"
        .Filters.Add "Word 2007 Template", "*.dotx"
        .Show
    End With

    Set FileSelected = FilePick.SelectedItems

    If FileSelected.Count <> 0 Then

        For Each WordFile In FileSelected

            FileJob = WordFile

            Set WorkDoc = Application.Documents.Open(FileJob, , , , , , , , , , , False)

            Set WholeDoc = WorkDoc.Content
            Set FooterDoc = WorkDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            Set FooterPage1 = WorkDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range

            With FooterPage1
                .Find.Execute Find1, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace1, wdReplaceAll
                .Find.Execute Find2, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace2, wdReplaceAll
                .Find.Execute Find3, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace3, wdReplaceAll
            End With

            With FooterDoc
                .Find.Execute Find1, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace1, wdReplaceAll
                .Find.Execute Find2, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace2, wdReplaceAll
                .Find.Execute Find3, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace3, wdReplaceAll
            End With

            With WholeDoc.Find
                .Execute Find1, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace1, wdReplaceAll
                .Execute Find2, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace2, wdReplaceAll
                .Execute Find3, True, True, , , , True, , , Replace3, wdReplaceAll

            End With

            WorkDoc.Save
            WorkDoc.Close

        Next

    End If

    MsgBox "Completed"

DoReplace_Exit:

    Set WholeDoc = Nothing
    Set FilePick = Nothing

    Set WorkDoc = Nothing
    Set FooterDoc = Nothing

    Exit Sub

DoReplace_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure DoReplace of VBA Document ReplaceMulti"
    Resume DoReplace_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: This is your introduction to the fact that copy-and-paste programming is a bad thing. If you find yourself copying and pasting any section of code with only minor adjustments each time, rest assured that you are doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample of how to approach this situation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoReplace()

    Dim FilesSelected As FileDialogSelectedItems
    Dim WordFile As Variant    ' FileName placeholder in selected files loop

    Dim WorkDoc As Document
    Dim WholeDoc As Range
    Dim FooterDoc As Range
    Dim FooterPage1 As Range
    Dim arrPair(0 To 2, 0 To 1) As String


    On Error GoTo DoReplace_Error

    ' Load the Array with pairs
    arrPair(0, 0) = "FIND TEXT"
    arrPair(0, 1) = "REPLACE TEXT"
    arrPair(1, 0) = "FIND TEXT"
    arrPair(1, 1) = "REPLACE TEXT"
    arrPair(2, 0) = "FIND TEXT"
    arrPair(2, 1) = "REPLACE TEXT"

    ' Get all the selected files
    Set FilesSelected = GetSelectedFiles

    If FilesSelected.Count <> 0 Then

        For Each WordFile In FilesSelected

            Set WorkDoc = Application.Documents.Open(WordFile, , , , , , , , , , , False)

            Set WholeDoc = WorkDoc.Content
            Set FooterDoc = WorkDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            Set FooterPage1 = WorkDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range

            ' Replace the values
            Call FindAndReplace(arrPair, WholeDoc)
            Call FindAndReplace(arrPair, FooterDoc)
            Call FindAndReplace(arrPair, FooterPage1)

            WorkDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Next

    End If

    MsgBox "Completed"

DoReplace_Exit:

    Set WholeDoc = Nothing

    Set WorkDoc = Nothing
    Set FooterDoc = Nothing

    Exit Sub


DoReplace_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure DoReplace of VBA Document ReplaceMulti"
    Resume DoReplace_Exit

End Sub

' Procedure to find and replace.
Sub FindAndReplace(ByVal arrValuePair As Variant, ByRef oSection As Object)

    Dim i As Long

    If UBound(arrValuePair, 2) = 1 Then
        With oSection
            For i = LBound(arrValuePair, 1) To UBound(arrValuePair, 1)
                .Find.Execute arrValuePair(i, 0), True, True, , , , True, , , arrValuePair(i, 1), wdReplaceAll
            Next i
        End With
    End If

End Sub


' Function to get the collection of selected files.
Function GetSelectedFiles() As FileDialogSelectedItems

    Dim FilePick As FileDialog

    Set FilePick = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FilePick
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Choose Report Template"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Word Documents & Templates", "*.do*"
        .Filters.Add "Word 2003 Document", "*.doc"
        .Filters.Add "Word 2003 Template", "*.dot"
        .Filters.Add "Word 2007 Document", "*.docx"
        .Filters.Add "Word 2007 Template", "*.dotx"
        .Show
    End With

    'Return the value
    Set GetSelectedFiles = FilePick.SelectedItems

End Function
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Just what I needed! I'm really grateful! You saved my ass!

Comment: Not a problem :) I guess that makes me an ass-savior. :)